# Where and how to set protocol delegate when slide out menu implemented in navigation controller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, delegates, protocols

Imagine you have the following storyboard scheme:

[Slide out menu UITableView and feed UITableView embedded in Nav controllers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0YDEV.png)

You want to filter out your feed based on the content of the cell that is tapped in the slide out menu.

As you can see on the storyboard scheme I shared above, you want to do this dynamically using only one segue whose identifier is:

```
@"Filter_MenuItem"
```

You declared the following protocol in the slide out menu view controller:

```
//  SlideOutMenuTableViewController.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "SlideOutMenuItems.h"
#import "SlideOutMenuCellTableViewCell.h"

@protocol filterFeed <NSObject>

-(void)filterFeedFromSlideOutItemTapped:(NSString *)slideOutItemStringData; //String to pass slideOut menu item string back to feed
@end


@interface SlideOutMenuTableViewController : UITableViewController

@property(nonatomic,assign)id<filterFeed> stringDelegate;

@end
```

And you implement the protocol method `filterFeedFromSlideOutItemTapped:`in your feed view controller:

```
#pragma mark - Filter feed based on slideout menu item tapped

-(void)filterFeedFromSlideOutItemTapped:(NSString *)slideOutItemStringData
{
    NSLog(@"filterFeedFromSlideOutItemTapped just started");
    if (!(slideOutItemStringData == (nil)))
        {//Pass self.feed.flames + filtering string ==> filtered flames
            NSMutableArray* allFlames = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:self.feed.flames];
            NSString *flameRelationFilter = slideOutItemStringData;
            NSPredicate* sortFlames = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(kFlameRelation like %@)", flameRelationFilter];
            NSArray* filteredFlames = [allFlames filteredArrayUsingPredicate:sortFlames];
            NSLog(@"The filter flames are %@", filteredFlames);
            NSMutableArray *mutableFilteredFlames = [filteredFlames mutableCopy];
            self.filteredFeed.flames = mutableFilteredFlames;

            [self.tableView reloadData];

        }
}
```

You make sure to synthesize your delegate in the implementation of your slide out menu view controller: `@synthesize stringDelegate;`

And before you call your protocol method in the implementation of your slide out menu view controller:

```
[stringDelegate filterFeedFromSlideOutItemTapped:[self.slideOutMenuItems menuItemAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

you know that, first, you need to initialize your protocol delegate:

```
instanceOfSlideOutMenuTableViewController.stringDelegate=self;
```

Generally, you do that successfully in a "prepareForSegue" method.  But this time it's more complicated since you implemented a slide out menu (you actually didn't reinvent the wheel, you picked your implementation [here](https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController)).

Where and how should you initialize your protocol delegate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you use `SWRevealViewController` which adds other controllers as child controllers, you can directly access feed controller from menu using `parentViewController`.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
  // get reveal controller
  SWRevealViewController *revealController = (SWRevealViewController *)self.navigationController.parentViewController;

  // get content controller
  UINavigationController *feedNavController = (UINavigationController *)revealController.frontViewController;

  // rename "FeedController" to whatever class you use for front controller
  FeedController *feedController = (FeedController *)feedNavController.topViewController;

  // get menu item
  NSString *menuItem = [self.slideOutMenuItems menuItemAtIndex:indexPath.row];

  // pass selected item to feed controller
  [feedController filterFeedFromSlideOutItemTapped:menuItem];
}
```

Comment: Updated my answer to reflect the use of navigation controllers.

Comment: Thank you @Andy.  Your solution is very elegant.  Great expertise.

Answer (score 0):

as i seen your storyboard you used SWRevealViewController to add the slider in your main bundle . you added a tableview to show the list of menu . so use "tableviewdidSelect" method to add your view controller to SwWRevealMain view that added your main view on the main Screen.